# Syntax highlighting for shell scripts broken

Tags: syntax-highlighting, bash, vim9, filetype-sh

Since recently my syntax highlighting for `ft=sh` (also `syn=sh` is set) is broken:

[image]

Why is that? How can I fix it?

Edit:

I'm using Vim 9.0 with patches 1-1302.

I add here the code from the screenshot. The code does not matter much, though. Syntax highlighting is broken for all my bash scripts that I checked. It seems to work for a few lines, before it breaks down.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Here is a comment. In yellow.

foo=bar
bar=baz
baz="${1}"

if [ "${foo}" == "bar" ]; then
    bar=foo
elif [ "${foo}" == "baz" ]; then
    bar=oof
fi

# Here is a comment. In green?

cd "$HOME"
mv x y
echo hello world

# Whatever I do, all is green.
```

Comment: I can reproduce your problem on Vim 9.0. It seems the problem is not on Vim 8.2. I suppose it deserve a big report in Vim.

Comment: It would help if you could add the text of your script together with the screenshot. To reproduce the problem we gain a bit of time ;-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt, I edited my post. Since you can reproduce the problem, would you suggest to open an issue on vim's github repository?

Comment: I can confirm that the syntax is fine in vim 8.1. A diff of `syntax_checkers/sh/sh.vim` shows no difference between the two versions though. Am I looking at the wrong file? Or does the issue lay elsewhere?

Comment: `syntax_checkers/sh/sh.vim` is part of ALE, which has nothing to do with syntax highlighting. Look for `syntax/sh.vim` instead, both in your own runtime and in the system one.

Comment: Indeed, we could verify that it is not configuration based starting Vim with `vim --clean` and open an issue in Vim github. Thanks for the edition :-)

Comment: I have seen several bug reports about the sh syntax file recently, but i do not know if any were this bad

Comment: I'm encountering the same exact issue on Arch.

Comment: I am guessing, this is the following issue, please try the linked workaround: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11937#issuecomment-1421116531

Comment: "It seems to work for a few lines, before it breaks down." After an empty line it breaks.Sometimes it goes back to working later in the fille. If you take out all empty lines it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a known bug which is fixed in the author's source code, see [author's reply](https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/c/qaw5JHA2zxY/m/ieLq_uMjAgAJ).

It should appear sometime in the future in main vim runtime.

Comment: I just did a `brew upgrade vim` and it solved the problem.  The author's reply above notes this is fixed in 9.0.1400

Comment: I installed the `brew install vim` which has version of `vim 9.1.0100` still have issues with bash, my entire code looks in the same color :/

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to 8.2 version of VIM because it's VIM9 bug (not ALE plugin bug):

```
mkdir ~/temp; 
git clone --branch v8.2.5172 https://github.com/vim/vim.git ~/temp/vim; 
cd ~/temp/vim;

make clean distclean
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-python3interp=yes 
make -j4
# Install globally:
sudo make install
```

Comment: That is a drastic solution, most likely you just need to update the syntax script for sh files, see e.g. here: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11937#issuecomment-1421116531

Comment: Welcome vi.SE @VladSavitsky. Downgrading will loose all other enhancements of newer version won't it? Weird.

Comment: For me it's more important to have working version of vim then to get enhancements of newer version so this is solution for cases like this. I have all I need in vim8 and do not loose anything with this downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading `vim` didn't work for me ( version `9.1` mentioned in the comment above )

I ended up just updating the `sh.vim` file itself from the fix mentioned in

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/albertyw/dotfiles/e787d02d754883d02021811421906ce861a3b993/files/vim/syntax/sh.vim > ~/.vim/syntax/sh.vim
```

That worked for me